# Visual Studio 2013 only showing Silverlight apps when making Windows Phone App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-8, visual-studio-2013

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition on Windows 8 and when I go to create a new project, all the apps I see are for Silverlight.

Is this how it should be or did I miss some SDK or something?

[image]

Comment: I thought it was some XAML project or something?

Comment: update to Windows 8.1, install the WP8.1 SDK and look if you see the normal Phone templates now.

Comment: Frank, Silverlight apps do use XAML. Are you trying to create a WinRT app or a Silverlight app? They both can use C#/XAML. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target WP8.1 on Windows 8 - you need Windows 8.1.

WinRT apps (i.e. non-Silverlight) on Windows Phone are only compatible with Windows Phone 8.1.

Upgrade Windows to 8.1, and make sure you also have the latest WP8.1 SDK installed.

Basically your dev machine's Windows version must at least match the target Windows version (including Windows Phone).

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 and installed the WP 8.1 Update from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43719. But i still only choose a Silverlight template. Can you help me ?

Comment: That link is for the WP8.1 emulators only, not the actual SDK. I'm not sure if there is an actual SDK download or if it's part of Visual Studio. Check this site: http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk and make sure you have everything installed, including updating Visual Studio (and I think you must have Visual Studio 2013 to build for WP 8.1).